# ReactiveMongoRepository / MongoRepository does not return _id field

Tags: mongodb, kotlin

I think this issue probably has to do with my Mongo Document Koltin Data class, but for our business case we need to allow the user to add on any JSON fields to describe their RF data set.

Extending the BasicDBObject was the best way I have found.

The mono being returned when I save a SigMfMetaDocument does not contain the _id field.

1. I cannot figure out why the save method does not return a Mono wrapping a SigMfDocument with and _id
2. If there is a better way to create a Type for ReactiveMongoRepository that can dynamically accept any fields I am all ears.

`@Document(collection = "sigmfmeta")`

```
class SigMfMetaDocument : BasicDBObject {

@Id
@JsonProperty("id")
val id: String? = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

constructor(map: Map<String, Any>) : super(map)

constructor() : super()

constructor(key: String, value: Object): super()
}
```

`@Repository
interface SigMfMetaRepository : ReactiveMongoRepository<SigMfMetaDocument, String>`

Comment: I'm no expert on mongo repos, but my guess is, that the multiple constructors are somehow messing things up. most examples use a simple `@Document data class Person(val id: String, val name: String)` or similar. Maybe first try that and if that works, then try to incrementally figure out what's wrong.

Comment: thanks for the reply @Lovis!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a way to solve this for my use case.  I was originally assuming the description in the documentation for the save method would apply 
(Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely).

My thought Mongo auto inserting the `_id` value would apply to this description.

I changed my model to:

```
@Document(collection = "sigmfmeta")
class SigMfMetaDocument : BasicBSONObject {

    constructor(map: Map<String, Any>) : super(map) {
        val id = ObjectId()
        this.put("_id", id)
    }

    constructor() : super()
}
```

This way I have the _id value after saving for some business logic.  Again I defined my Model this way because the metadata file we are accepting needs to allow a client to add any fields they wish to describe a binary file of RF measurement data.